# How to add an "if otherwise" clause to evaluation in Sympy?

Tags: sympy

How would I implement the following in Sympy?

```
if x > y
    z = x - y
otherwise 
    Z = 0
```

I've looked at assumptions, but I am still lost.

Comment: Thank you smackenzie for editing the post and making it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the examples on [this](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise) page.

```
import sympy as s
x, y = s.symbols('x,y')

z = s.Piecewise( ( x-y, x > y), (0, True))

z.subs([(x,1),(y,2)])

z.subs([(x,2),(y,1)])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I don't have enough reputation to give the answer an up-vote, sorry about that.

Comment: I think you can accept answers by pressing the tick mark on the left. You don't need reputation for that because it is your question. Anyways best of luck.